# Retina , non retina images, showing white background

Tags: ios, retina-display

I have an app where the designer has given me assets or png's in two formats, non retin and retina,well formatted and named with @2 properly.
the retina images work fine, but the non retina images show a weird white background behind them. anyone ever experience this?

[image]
[image]

Here in those two images, they are both showing against a black uiview, when running retina the arrow fills with a black background, but for non retina devices its a white background.

Comment: If your image name is one.png then you have to save the retina image as one@2x.png

Comment: Check: 1. the must have the same name one!=One, 2.If your image view is in IB you must give the name of one.png, the imageView will take care about the one to load, 3.Control your view frames

Comment: yes all of those I checked,

Comment: Are you creating imageview programmatically or through XIB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's the problem, but from your question it look like you forgot @2x in the name of your image.
For non-retina display the correct name is youImage.png and for retina youImage@2x.png

Check your youImage.png in photoshop (for example) and check if the background is not part of the image itself. It append to me more than one...

**Edit:**
Since you added the two picture in your post, I can confirm: 
Your non-retina picture (the small on) got white background embedded. Ask your designer to remove it and use a transparent background.

**Edit2:**
Try with this picture as non-retina image. I removed the background for you (quick and durty just to test)
=====> 
[image]

**Edit3:**
I edited your image and set a red background. Now you can clearly see that your non-retina image embed a background.
[image]

Comment: hi, so I do have the @2x , and for retina images it works fine, its for the non retina images I have this white background

Comment: Are you sure it's not part of the picture itself ? Because of some design mistake ?

Comment: I;ve added two images as an example

Comment: @funkycoldmedia so it's exactly what I'm saying. You retina picture got a transparent background but your non-retina picture got a white background embedded in the picture. Ask your designer to remove the white background in the non-retina picture.

Comment: hmm, you know I am not a graphics guy, but I do see that when you import them into xcode and click on the image one will say alpha channel yes, the other alpha channel no.

Comment: @MartinMagakian Martin, no need to clean the bg from the small image. Just save the big one with 50% size.

Comment: @funkycoldmedia "alpha channel yes" mean that you png image is capable of doing transparent background. But it doesn't mean it is doing it.

Comment: thnx, will go and prepare to kill the graphics guy, I think I'll make a clorox cocktail for him.

Comment: @funkycoldmedia haha good idea. But to be honest it's a common mistake. I made it myself few times...